# Replacing one character in a long list of file names

Tags: batch-rename

I have a list of image files (jpg, png, etc...) that the dot before the suffix was replaced with # this makes the file unrecognizable to the Android os. In dos, it would be easy. How can I do it in js easily because I've never used js before?

Comment: By `js` if you mean `Node.js`, you can use the `fs` library. Could you show any examples of what you have already tried?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. But reading the similar questions on this site, im sure im in over my head. In the wonderful old days of DOS, I'd of done it with a simple  rename command with a couple arguments after it. To answer your other question, by js I meant JavaScript. I don't know what fs is. Thank you for your help and time answering. I'll keep plugging away at it.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, and sorry for the assumption. [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) is a module that ships with `node.js`, which is a commonly used JavaScript runtime. What kind of environment are you using to execute your JavaScript code?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Node.js, you can use the [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module.

I haven't been able to make time to test a solution, but a naive implementation would look probably like this:

```
// Import the fs module
const fs = require('fs');

// Read all files in directory
var files = fs.readDirSync('/path/to/images/folder/');

// Loop through the files and rename each file
files.forEach(path => fs.rename(path, path.replace('#', '.')));
```